# Store data in Local Storage is a good practice?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using the local storage to store data(values, menu etc. ), is it good practice in programing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is inherently no more secure than using cookies. They are very similar to cookies, but can only be read client-side, whereas Cookies are sent to the server when visiting a site that has them. This could, in some systems, make Local Storage less secure, as it can only be read by the client side JS code, which can be modified.

There is no security on either Cookies or Local Storage, requiring you to make your own security if you want it. They are both good practice to use in certain situations, mainly when security is not a priority and you want to for example, save settings or count visits to a site.

FYI: [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is not a Chrome-only feature. The [Chrome Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) is a Chrome only storage mechanism used for Chrome and Chromium extensions. It works the same as local storage, but with a few differences. Be sure not to be confused by the two.